# Вопрос по стилистике

Tags: стилистика

Слова "внезапно, неожиданно, вдруг" являются схожими по смыслу, и вместе их не пишут (плеоназм или смысловая избыточность). Однако в художественной литературе, как у современных авторов, так и у классиков, подобные словосочетания встречаются: "Вдруг неожиданно...". "Внезапно вдруг..." (слова автора, не речь персонажей). Что вы думаете по этому поводу, насколько гармоничны для восприятия подобные словосочетания, если встречаются в литературе?

Comment: Я думаю, что таких случаях, когда пишут "вдруг внезапно", слово "вдруг" является авторской оценкой, а "неожиданно" отражает уже впечатление фокальных персонажей. Получается, если развёрнуто, так: "Но вдруг для нас с с тобой, читатель, произошёл неожиданный поворот: внезапно для всех присутствующих в комнату вбежала зебра".

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! Очень интересная мысль. Как раз вчера я думала примерно о том же, но мне не удавалось сложить размышления воедино. Прочитав ваш комментарий, картина сложилась и стала более ясной:)